# Adding an additional parameter to the url

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url in my website

http://mywebsite.com/settings.php?action=invoice

I need to redirect it to

http://mywebsite.com/settings.php?action=invoice&view=all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /settings\.php\?action=invoice(\ |$)
rewriterule ^ /settings\.php?action=invoice&view=all [L,R]
```